# Find reference for namespace in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference, namespaces

I am working on a c# project. It reference quite a few packages and there are packages referencing other packages. So a namespace used in the program does not necessarily come from a direct reference.
For a specific using statement, is there a way to find out which reference (by reference, I mean the external DLL's/NuGet packages) it is originated from?
Thank you.

For example project reference a Nuget Package called Package1. In Package1 we have namespace called Namespace1. Then Package1 references Package2, which have a namespace called Namespace2.
In your code you could have

```
using Namespace2;
```

But how do you know which assembly or Nuget Package Namespace2 is originated from (in this case Package1)?

Comment: Right-click the `using` statement and choose _Find All References_ .

Comment: @DavidTansey sorry I wasn't clear. I updated my question. The reference I am taking about is the external reference such as DLL's and NuGet packages. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a native means in Visual Studio to do this.  However, [JetBrains ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) can do this.  Note that a single namespace import isn't tied to a single assembly.  A namespace import (using statement) can easily bring types from several different assemblies into scope.

With ReSharper in hand I simply selected the namespace and pressed F12.  You can see that `System.Collections.Generic` is defined in four assemblies referenced by this project.

[image: ReSharper namespace find]

Comment: Thanks this seems to be what I need so I tried it out. While it seems to work with a lot of the System assemblies, however I am not sure if it is because there is only one assembly for my namespace, it does not work for me very well. Most of the time it just sends me to Assembly Explorer and shows me the references that the namespace uses. Is there any other way to get the origin assembly?

Comment: When you're sent directly to the Assembly Explorer you are looking at the one assembly that defines the namespace.

Comment: In this case, the assembly that shows up is actually not in my reference list. So I think the assembly comes from one of the packages being referenced. If that's the case, is there anyway to tell which package it is originated from? Thank you.

Comment: Right click on the assembly in the Assembly Explorer and select, Open Containing Folder.  At that point, based on the folder path, the package should be apparent.

Comment: Hmmm it points to an assembly in my NuGet cache. But I removed that package from the project previously. Now I am really confused where this reference is coming from.

Comment: @HenryYu I know it's been a while but did you ever figure out how to solve this? 
I'm having the same problem, where I have a `using namespace` but I cannot figure out what dependency is providing me with it :(

Comment: @AlvaroAlbero Sorry I don't recall now. But here's a very manual idea I just thought about: try deleting the name space's using statement. Then if there is any code in the file that uses that using statement, VS should show error for them. So now you know which code uses that namespace. Then put the namespace back and go to the reference of the code that uses the namespace. Hopefully that directs you to an assembly that indicates which package the namespace is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

I tried [harlam357's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/425465/harlam357) answer in visual studio 2019 but it failed (the image bellow).

1.

[image]

Then, I did a trick. I turned the  reference in to a comment and found the error line which implements a method belong the namespace. Through the method I got the root reference.

2.

[image]

3. 

[image]

4. 

[image]